# Do opaque glass make sense?

Tags: modifiers

As you know glass is a transparent (or translucent) substance, however can opaque glass make sense? I don't use a metaphor but I want to talk about a literal sense.[image]

For another example, can the orange in the picture above be called 'blue orange' even though 'orange' means orange color fruit?

Comment: @TypelA I know but I mean 'golden apple' means 'golden green or red apple' because 'apple' means 'red thing'?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Apples come in different colors, including red, green _and yellow_. You seem to know this. _Gold_ is a yellowish color. Something that is gold-colored is _golden_. Hence, golden apple. "Apple" does not mean "red thing," it means the fruit of a _Malus domestica_ tree.

Comment: @TypelA so I defined apple as the round fruit of a tree of the rose family, which has thin green or red skin and crisp flesh

Comment: I guess we're talking about different fruits. Like [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygium)? I have to admit I'm not familiar with this fruit, and it's not what most English speakers think of when you say "apple" by itself. Is this really a horticulture question? Are you asking if this particular fruit has a yellow variety?

Comment: @TypelA I give you another example, if 'sky' means 'blue sky,'  is 'yellow sky' a contradiction?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't get it. Another example: "if 1 + 1 = 3, then is 2 > 3 a contradiction?" You are defining a thing in an unusual way, then changing the definition and asking if it's a contradiction. It's meaningless. Yes, apples can be yellow. No, apple doesn't automatically denote a color.

Comment: I think I should change the example.

Comment: This is not a question about English.   You can use language correctly to describe things that don't and can't exist  "green ideas" That is a correct English phrase just as '緑のI考え' is a valid Japanese one, but a meaningless one in any language.  So the question is not about English

Comment: @James K But you should admit that there's no place to post simple linguistic questions

Comment: I think that this is a bad question. You're asking two different questions, when ideally a question should only contain one. What do you want to know about: opaque glass or blue oranges?

Comment: @nick012000 blue orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does opaque glass make sense?

Absolutely! There doesn't need to be anything symbolic or metaphoric about it.

There exists a manufacturing process where they mix some additional material into the glass that makes it "hazy" (usually white in color) to the point that it's barely transparent any more.

I recall seeing various kitchen equipment of this sort, like bowls, plates, cups, and in particular, heat-resistant baking utensils.

Their appearance can often be characterized with a "milky" impression, and they get decorated with moderate amounts of colorful (hand-) painted ornaments.

Comment: Though the dictionary defines glass is translucent or transparent (not opaque), it doesn't matter?

Comment: The dictionary was narrow-sighted in this case. Or perhaps, they had a limited space for the word definitions, and they could not afford to go into details about something that applies only to 3% of all glass products. Though I still think they should have been able to squeeze in the modifier "_most often_ transparent" into a definition describing glass.

Comment: Some alcoholic beverages are distributed in bottles made of entirely opaque glass. My after-shave sits in an opaque glass flask. You will likely find numerous further examples to products packaged in opaque glass in a drogerie's body-care product-lineup.

Comment: I have a black glass vase that is entirely opaque.